# RavenDB .Include() not working with int ids

Tags: ravendb

RavenDB [used to not accept](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ravendb/en4e277_lB4/qFx47lesBfUJ) Includes when the id fields were ints instead of strings.
 But [the documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/handling-document-relationships) does not mention this limitation.

Is there any workaround that does not require changing the ids from int to strings in the .Net object model.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a property that contains just the integer id of a related document, you can do this:

```
 session.Include<User, Item>( user => user.ItemId).Load(1);
```

This will load users/1 and then get the value inside that user's ItemId and use the "items/" prefix to load the related item.

Comment: This does not work when there is an array of ids (e.g. `user.ItemIds`).